# Создание виртуального шлюза VirtualBox

Tags: сеть, virtualbox, виртуальная-машина, шлюз

Здравствуйте! Подскажите куда копать или где можно почитать информацию по созданию шлюза, чтобы объединить несколько виртуальных машин в одну сеть в VirtualBox?
На одном компьютере есть несколько установленных операционных систем в VirtualBox. Необходимо объединить их в одну сеть со статическими адресами.

Answer (score 5):

Из хелпа к VirtualBox:

> Bridged networking
>
> This is for more advanced networking needs such as network simulations and running servers in a guest. When enabled, VirtualBox connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network packets directly, circumventing your host operating system's network stack.
>
> Internal networking
>
> This can be used to create a different kind of software-based network which is visible to selected virtual machines, but not to applications running on the host or to the outside world.
>
> Host-only networking
>
> This can be used to create a network containing the host and a set of virtual machines, without the need for the host's physical network interface. Instead, a virtual network interface (similar to a loopback interface) is created on the host, providing connectivity among virtual machines and the host.

Общий смысл примерно такой:

- "мостовое соединение" позволяет включить виртуальные машины в существующую реальную сеть. Это, к примеру, позволяет виртуальным машинам, запущенным на разных хостах, соединенных в сеть, видеть друг друга.
- "внутренняя сеть" позволяет объединить виртуальные машины в сеть, недоступную извне
- "виртуальный адаптер хоста" позволяет объединить виртуалки в сеть, также доступную для машины, на которой они запущены.

Таким образом, вам нужно выбрать один из вариантов, указать на всех виртуальных машинах нужный тип подключения (свойства машины -> сеть -> тип подключения) и прописываете статические адреса (точно так же, как это делается на реальных машинах).

Answer (score 0):

Если несколько виртуальных машин работают на одной реальной - то копать скорее всего в сторону `internal netwoeking`. Это позволит организовать сеть между виртуальными машинами и изолировать эту виртуальную сеть от основной.