# Как соединить виртуальные машины (VirtualBox) с другими машинами в ЛВС

Tags: сеть, virtualbox

На каждом из 2-х ноутбуков стоит VirtualBox.

Локальная машина: Windows 7  192.168.1.7/24

Виртуальная: Ubuntu  192.168.1.101/24

Установлено соединение типа мост. Машины между друг другом пингуются, а между маршрутизатором и другими хостами сети -  нет. Маршруты на винде сбрасывал,прописывал, ничего не вышло.

[image: BridgeVB]

Заметил, что подключение типа мост не с 2-мя сетевыми интерфейсами, а в свойствах сетевой карты поставлена галка VirtualBox Bridging networking driver
[image: Сетевой мост VBOX]

Таблица маршрутизации на Windows 7

[image: Таблица маршрутизации на Windows 7]

Так же в ОС есть адаптер VirtualBox, но я так понял он нужен для NAT

[image: Adapter Vbox]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и на последок ICMP запросы

[image: ICMP windows]

ICMP  из гостевой системы

[image: ICMP из гостевой системы]

arp windows[image: arp Windows]

Comment: Просто меняете на виртуалках тип подключения на "виртуальный адаптер хоста", и виртуалки станут доступны из локальной сети.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Создание виртуального шлюза VirtualBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/151543/1365)

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. Не пингуется https://yadi.sk/d/SWcdulX83YHaPK

Comment: @insolor К сожалению не помогло. Не пингуется yadi.sk/d/SWcdulX83YHaPK