# Почему не работают сетевые интерфейсы от VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, интерфейс, virtualbox, kali-linux

Понадобилась винда семёрка в качестве виртуалки. Сначала все было хорошо, сетевые интерфейсы спокойно пахали, роутер видел машину в локалке. После перезагрузки ПК перестали работать сетевые интерфейсы. Пытался удалять и создавать новые, но все безуспешно. Если же подключаюсь по NAT то все пашет, но роутер не видит машину...

Как исправить?

- Основная ОС: Kali Linux
- Виртуальная машина: Oracle VM VirtualBox

Comment: Помнится, в настройках сети в VirtualBox, я прописывл что-то вроде bridge для типа сетевого устройства виртуалки (но прошло много лет, могу ошибаться)

Comment: @avp, странно... До этого работало через виртуальный адаптер хоста, а через мост нет... Теперь наоборот XD

Comment: @avp, напиишите ответ, я приму его ;)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Создание виртуального шлюза VirtualBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/151543/1365)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В подобных случаях имеет смысл попробовать установить в настройках VirtualBox тип сетевого интерфейса в **bridge**.